# How to use p.adjust

Tags: r

The code below runs t-test (un-paired) using 2 matrices as input and returns p-values but can someone show me the exact code needed to generate the p.adjusted values aka the `FDR` corrected/adjusted p.values (p.adjust)

```
m1 <-go_samp_matrix_data[grep(paste(input$mychooser2$left, collapse='|'), rownames(go_samp_matrix_data), ignore.case=TRUE),]
m2 <-go_samp_matrix_data[grep(paste(input$mychooser2$right, collapse='|'), rownames(go_samp_matrix_data), ignore.case=TRUE),]

ttestmat1<-sapply(seq(ncol(m1)), function(x) f(m1[,x], m2[,x]))  

f <- function(x,y){
  test <- t.test(x,y, paired=FALSE)
  out <- data.frame(pval = sprintf("%.3f", test$p.value))
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: Its good you have added some code, but it is a bit unclear what is going on with it: you dont use your function or ttestmat (we also dont have m1 or m2). If your question is as stated perhaps it would be better to just add two random vectors to your question, and show your attempt to calculate the adjusted p-value. Then it will be easier to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a vector of p-values, say `p.vect`. Then you simply include that in `p.adjust()` like so:

```
p.adjust(p.vect, "fdr")
```

Comment: Thanks Noah, your comments helped me get the answer that I was looking for.